# Warning when passing non-const parameter to a function that expects const parameter. Is there a better way?

Tags: c, gcc, constants

I am trying to pass a parameter to a function, and indicate that the parameter should be considered `const` by the receiving function.

It was my understanding that the following code example shows the only way to ensure that the `test` function can be called with the `argv` variable, which is not declared as const.

```
void test(const char * const *arr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
{
    test(argv);
}

void test(const char * const *arr)
{
}
```

However, gcc gives me a warning such as the following:

```
E:\Projects\test>gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:5:2: warning: passing argument 1 of 'test' from incompatible pointer type
[enabled by default]
test.c:1:6: note: expected 'const char * const*' but argument is of type 'char **'
```

This leads me to believe that what I am doing here is somehow wrong.
Is there a better way to pass a parameter to a function, and indicate that it should be considered `const` by the receiving function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html) explains why in C there is a safe guard when converting a pointers to non-`const`to `const`. In your case of a doubly `const` qualified target pointer the problem that is described there wouldn't occur, I think. So C++ has a relaxed rule that would allow the implicit conversion that you are asking for. Unfortunately for C the standards committee found the rule from C++ too complicated, so you'd have to cast your pointer to the expected type.

Comment: I like the snark in the FAQ, "as always, the need for such a cast may indicate a deeper problem". The counter-snark is yes, it indicates a deeper problem, the language isn't smart enough ;-)

Comment: +1 for good citation. The POSIX rationale for the `exec` family of functions also addresses the issue well, and why they chose the form they did: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it such as:

```
void test(const char * const *arr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
{
   test((const char * const *)argv);
}

void test(const char * const *arr)
{
}
```

This will make the warning go away. This is okay provided you can actually treat `argv` as a `const char * const *` in your function.