# C: Initialize a constant string array dynamically

Tags: c, arrays, string

I know the problem seems weird but I need to initialize (or convert) a constant string array in C.

The problem is that the string array is initialized dynamically but an API function I'd like to use only accepts constant string arrays.

I know that this works:

```
const char *const arr[] = { "test" };
```

But again: Since I don't know how many items the array will have nor I know the content pre runtime, I can't initialize the array that way.

So of course this won't work

```
const char *const arr[1]; 
arr[1] = "test"; // won't work
```

My question is: Is it possible to convert somehow the dynamically string array to a read-only one? Or is there a way to initialize the array dynamically once?

EDIT 1: My exact problem

```
int len = 8;
const char *names1[8] = {"test0","test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7" }; // not what I'm looking for
const char *names2[len]; 
const char *names3[len];

// nearly what I'm looking for
for(int j=0; j<len; j++) {
    names2[j] = "test";
}

// exactly what I'm looking for
for(int j=0; j<len; j++) {
    sprintf(names3[j],"%s%d","test",j); // discards 'const' qualifier
}

// ...

Cudd_DumpDot(gbm, 1, ddnodearray, names1, NULL, outfile);
Cudd_DumpDot(gbm, 1, ddnodearray, names2, NULL, outfile);
Cudd_DumpDot(gbm, 1, ddnodearray, names3, NULL, outfile); // won't work
```

Okay this is my progress so far.
The method with `names2` is indeed working but I'd like to use `sprintf` (as shown with `names3`) since I need to append `j` in this case. And this would wound the `const` qualifier.

Comment: Can you clarify in what way the API only accepts constant string arrays? Is it just declared `const char`, then you can pass `char` arrays as well. Or does it test the memory region the string is in?

Comment: If a function argument has the `const` modifier, it only means that the function will not mutate the data you pass. I.e. you can easily pass your dynamically allocated array as it is.

Comment: @KarstenKoop the requested argument from the API is `char const *const *  inames,` and if I try to pass a string array gcc says: `expected ‘const char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char **’`

Comment: @EliKorvigo but there is the warning `expected ‘const char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char **’` from gcc :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning when passing non-const parameter to a function that expects const parameter. Is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992407/warning-when-passing-non-const-parameter-to-a-function-that-expects-const-parame)

Comment: @Sonnywhite see my answer, you **must** have the first `const` in the type you pass, which refers to the data of the individual strings (the reasons are complicated, there are other questions explaining them), but you don't need the second one (referring to the pointers stored in the array). -- so you CAN put pointers in your array before passing it.

Comment: @Sonnywhite and [here's the reason why you need the first `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011978/const-causing-incompatible-pointer-type-why-only-for-double-pointers/45013356#45013356)

Comment: @KarstenKoop indeed a duplicate, but the answer given there is (IMHO) quite weak ...

Comment: @Sonnywhite The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834064/c-initialize-a-constant-string-array-dynamically#comment80616080_46834064) does not match the posted code.  The comment argument points to a `char *`.  Code's `arr` elements are `const char *`.  So the goal in your comment differs from the question's explanation.  Best  to post your _true_ failing code.

Comment: @chux I added the actual code and the API calls that causing the troubles..

Comment: Solved it with first `sprintf` the content to a non constant string array and then copy the contents to the const array with the method of @FelixPalmen. Thanks to all so far!

Comment: `const char *names3[len]; ...    sprintf(names3[j],"%s%d","test",j);` is bad code.

Answer (score 3):

Technically there is nothing stopping you from casting the pointer to (`char *`) and then setting the elements with `memset` or alike.

However this invokes undefined behaviour since the compiler *can* put it into read-only marked memory.

[Excerpt from an answer on another SO question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281664/2005038)

> The const qualifier is an instruction to the compiler to reject code
>   that attempts to modify that object directly; attempts to modify the
>   object indirectly (as you do in the second code snippet) results in
>   undefined behavior, meaning any result is possible.

**There is no way (without invoking UB) to change a constant after its initialisation - so don't do that.**

**UPDATE** As @chux pointed out in the comments it is indeed possible to **dynamically** initialize local variables.

Comment: `int  const x[2] = { rand(), rand()};` is a counter example to " no way ... to initialize a constant array dynamically.   No UB.  Your quote is about _assignment_.  ("attempts to modify").  _Initialization_ is something else - it is done at definition time and may be dynamic.

Comment: @chux Doesn't work for me: "test.c:7:19: error: initializer element is not constant"

Comment: @chux "Moreover, in C language the term "constant" refers to literal constants (like 1, 'a', 0xFF and so on) and enum members. Const-qualified objects (of any type) are not constants in C language terminology. They cannot be used in initializers of objects with static storage duration, regardless of their type." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w

Comment: `int const x[2] = {fn(),3};` is your example is in global space.  `int const x[2] = {fn(),3};` works fine as a local object.

Comment: OK, so code can locally create a `const` array dynamically.

Comment: Aside: C does not refer to `1, 'a', 0xFF` as literal constants.  The spec calls them _integer-constant_.  _Literal_ is used for _string literal_ and _complex literals_.

Comment: @chux Thanks! I've changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> an API function I'd like to use only accepts constant string arrays.

That's no reason to pass an array of constant pointers ... the conversion to `const` (in this case constant array elements) is allowed (and even implicit), so the following (nonsensical) code compiles just fine:

```
const char *test(const char *const *foo)
{
    return foo[0];
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *arr[10];
    arr[0] = "Foobar";

    const char *x = test(arr);
    return (int) *x;
}
```

Comment: That only works flawlessly if `arr` is an array of pointers to *`const`*. If you declare it with `char* arr[10];`, you get a warning from `gcc` (-Wincompatible-pointer-types).

Comment: Okay thanks, it actually works ... but there is one more problem: At the moment I set the content with `sprintf` since the content consist of strings and integers and stuff ... but with doing that gcc has now this problem: `passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type`

Comment: @Sonnywhite Allocate your array members as `char *` (e.g. with `char *x = malloc(size)`) and sprintf there, then put this pointer in your array like `a[0] = x;`. Again, this conversion is allowed and implicit.

Answer (score 1):

> Initialize a constant string array dynamically

Within a function, there are various ways to initialize a `const` string array at run-time.

```
// example
const char *s[2] = { (char [3]){ rand(), 0, 0},(char [3]){ rand(), 0, 0} };
```

---

Yet it appears OP needs only something like that.

Form the various strings, each in valid memory.

```
// Exmaple
#define SZ (4 + 11 + 1)
char buf[len][SZ];
for(int j=0; j<len; j++) {
  sprintf(buf[j],"%s%d","test",j);
}
```

Form an array of `const char *`

```
  const char *names[len];
  for(int j=0; j<len; j++) {
    names[len] = buf[len];
  }
```

Call `Cudd_DumpBlifBody()`.  The `char const *const *` parameters can be called with type `char const *const *` or `char const **`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void DdManager;
typedef void DdNode;
int Cudd_DumpBlifBody(DdManager *dd, int n, DdNode **f, 
    char const *const *inames, 
    char const *const *onames, FILE *fp, int mv) {
  return 0;
}
#define SZ (4 + 11 + 1)

int sw(int len) {
  char buf[len][SZ];
  const char *names[len];
  for(int j=0; j<len; j++) {
    sprintf(buf[j],"%s%d","test",j);
    names[len] = buf[len];
  }
  char const *const *inames = names;
  char const *const *onames = names;
  return Cudd_DumpBlifBody (NULL, 0, NULL, inames, onames, NULL, 0);
}
```

---

Local objects like `char buf[len][SZ];` could easlily get too large for local storage.  Consider `*alloc()` if unsure or if `len` could be large.